# Execute yii site on Microsoft iis

Tags: php, iis, yii, yii2

I've a problem with a yii site that I developed last day. I completed the developement on a PC with yii installed and then  I moved the site on another pc with microsoft iis installed. I've tried to connect to my site but I've received this error:

[image]
Sorry, the error is in Italian but it is an error 403.

How can I solve it? I can't use the console to launch yii on this pc.
Ty :D

[EDIT]

The requirements page:

[image]

Comment: Is php installed correctly on that iis server?

Comment: Yes, the requirement page works

Comment: type /web behind the current url. I think you are missing some web.config

Comment: Go to http://localhost/ecm-2016---yii/basic/web and what do you see?

Comment: Yeah, in http://localhost/ecm-2016---yii/basic/web/ i see my site